# Improper placing of relativelayout fields

Tags: android, android-layout, android-relativelayout

Only textView1 is appearing on screen, button and edittext box is not appearing. Please check my code. I am new to android development. I believe that the placement of edittext and button is incorrect.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/textView1" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/edit_message"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="10dp"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="@string/edit_message"/>

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/edit_message"
        android:layout_marginTop="49dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/edit_message"
        android:onClick="sendMessage"
        android:text="@string/button_send" />


</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Take take ``+`` away from e.g ``android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"``. You're introducing "new" id here, not laying out below existing view with given id.

Comment: tried but not working. I am using this as a refrence http://www.mkyong.com/android/android-relativelayout-example/

Comment: @harism I have always used the `@+id/` for layouts and never had any problems. Could you explain this further or give a link?

Comment: Ah ok, it may be the case I am mistaken and it doesn't matter if you use ``+id`` when referring to existing id. Still, what happens if you do not have the ``+id`` reference in place? Do you even get an error for non existing reference id?

Comment: same error even after removing +id

Comment: @TronicZomB the `@+id/x` is for adding a new id to your application resources - the first reference to `x` (top-down) in that XML file, which is _usually_ where you'd assign it to an element (`android:id="@+id/x"`). If you need to refer to it in the same layout file, you use `@id/x`. If, like in RelativeLayout, you need to refer to `x` but the element hasn't been added, you can add the id in the reference (`android:layout_below="@+id/x"`) _then_ assign that id to the element `x` using `android:id="@id/x"`) (note, no `+`)

Answer (score 1):

`RelativeLayout` doesn't have an `orientation` property...remove that. Also, I think you want to remove the `marginTop` properties if putting them `below` other `Views`. You may want to use `padding` instead. I'm not sure if you can be to the right of and below the same `view` but that may work. That's all I see at the moment

**Note**

`fill_parent` is depricated. It's ok to use for now but you might as well get accustomed to using `match_parent` instead

I got your code working with the suggestions I gave. See below. Note with a `height` of 10dp you may not see it because that isn't very big

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="textView1" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/edit_message"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="10dp"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
    android:ems="10"
    android:hint="edit_message"/>

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/edit_message"
    android:onClick="sendMessage"
    android:text="button_send" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: I have removed orientation property and add padding also, but it is still not working
            <EditText
            android:id="@+id/edit_message"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="10dp"
            android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
            android:hint="@string/edit_message"
            android:padding="10dp" />

Comment: 10dp isn't very big. I would set `android:layout_height="wrap_content"` to start and make sure you have default text in there. You may also even want to remove the `padding` for now until you get it to show up just to eliminate it as a problem. When I have an issue like this, I copy what I think I will want it to have and start with the bare minimum to see where the problem is

Comment: Sorry so late, power has been out. I will try to look some more in a minute if those suggestions didn't work

Answer (score 0):

Everything appears to be good, except why don't you try anchoring your `TextView` somewhere, say the parent top left:

```
android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
android:layout_alignPatentLeft="true"
```

Also, you may want to research this more, but I feel that it is highly, highly discouraged to use the xml onClick and instead register the onClickListener in the java code.

Comment: By default, the `Views` are placed at the top left so those wouldn't do anything. Also, `onClick` is perfectly fine in xml. That just depends on the developer and their needs. I do it quite a bit. Just depends on the situation which is the easiest, cleanest, and most efficient

Comment: @codeMagic ok, I thought that they were anchored to the top left by defualt but wasn't sure. Also, I didn't know about the items you mentioned in your response. And that is good to know about the `onClick`. I just felt that I had read that that was bad practice but I guess I never looked into it mcuh since the java onClick worked for my purposes. Thanks for the info!

Comment: No problem. Yep, can be very handy to declare it in xml, depending on the situation, and I think makes the code look cleaner

Comment: @codeMagic yes it does look like it will clean up the code some. I'll keep it in mind from now on.

Answer (score 0):

Correct code. just remove

```
android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
 android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
```

from Edittext and use padding instead of marginTop

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
      android:layout_marginLeft="0dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="0dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
    android:background="#000000"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/textView1"
        android:textColor="#C8C8C8"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/edit_message"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+string/textView1"
            android:hint="@string/edit_message"
           />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignRight="@+id/edit_message"
            android:layout_below="@+id/edit_message"
            android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:onClick="sendMessage"
            android:text="@string/button_send" 
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
            />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: `alignParentLeft` shouldn't cause a problem since the OP is declaring it below the `TextView`